# iphone URL Scheme image upload app

Tags: iphone

I have developed an application to upload image captured from camera to server. I registered this app to URL Scheme so that i can access camera from web app.

I can able to launch the app from web app but do not know how to go back to the web page from where i launched the app.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is send the URL of the webapp to your app via your app URL sheme:

> myapp://callback=www.someurl.com

Then when your app is done just open the URL again.

Comment: I tried what you said, but callback url is opening in new page. I don't want that to happen, it should be in same page

Comment: how would i get callback value?

Comment: You can't go back to where you can from.

Comment: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html read this. You will need to write your own routine for getting the paramentes out of the `NSURL`